# Excel VBA - Add Function to Macro to Delete Rows Containing Specific Text

Tags: vba, excel

I'm new to this site, and to Excel. I've been working on creating a spreadsheet, and fumbling my way through automating it as much as I can in order to streamline it for myself and the other members of my team. It performs most of the tasks I would like it to, but there are still a few remaining. Here is my code as it stands currently:

```
Sub Setup()
'
' Setup Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+e
'
Rows("1:3").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.delete Shift:=xlUp
Cells.Select
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Panel1").Sort.SortFields.Clear
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Panel1").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("C1:C18") _
    , SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Panel1").Sort
    .SetRange Range("A1:Q18")
    .Header = xlGuess
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With
Columns("B:B").Select
Cells.Replace What:="RTA", Replacement:="DELETE", LookAt:=xlWhole, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=True, SearchFormat:=False, _
    ReplaceFormat:=False
Columns("C:C").Select
Selection.Copy
ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 2
ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 3
ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 4
ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 5
Columns("O:O").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("O1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
    TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=False, _
    Semicolon:=False, Comma:=True, Space:=False, Other:=False, FieldInfo _
    :=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1)), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
Columns("O:P").Select
With Selection
    .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
    .Orientation = 0
    .AddIndent = False
    .IndentLevel = 0
    .ShrinkToFit = False
    .MergeCells = False
End With
Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalDown).LineStyle = xlNone
Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalUp).LineStyle = xlNone
With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeLeft)
    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .ColorIndex = 0
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .Weight = xlThin
End With
With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeTop)
    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .ColorIndex = 0
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .Weight = xlThin
End With
With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .ColorIndex = 0
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .Weight = xlThin
End With
With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeRight)
    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .ColorIndex = 0
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .Weight = xlThin
End With
With Selection.Borders(xlInsideVertical)
    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .ColorIndex = 0
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .Weight = xlThin
End With
With Selection.Borders(xlInsideHorizontal)
    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .ColorIndex = 0
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .Weight = xlThin
End With
Columns("N:N").Select
ActiveWindow.LargeScroll ToRight:=-1
Columns("A:N").Select
Range("N1").Activate
Selection.EntireColumn.Hidden = True
End Sub
```

The thing I'm currently struggling with the most is adding a function to this Macro which will find a specific text string, and delete the entire row which contains it. I've seen a lot of people suggest using Autofilter, but I need the row to be deleted entirely, not just hidden. I've also found a lot of really great standalone solutions, but I can't seem to figure out how to integrate them into this Macro, only how to make them a new Module. And I've also attempted to incorporate a Delete Sheet Rows action into the Macro thinking that if I did a Find and Replace first, that it would only delete that particular row, but it ended up deleting my entire worksheet.

As I stated, what it does now is a Find (RTA) and Replace (DELETE), as I was attempting to go the Delete Sheet Rows route, but ultimately all I need it to do is search Column B for the text RTA and delete the row(s) which contain it.

Additionally, is there a way to have this run on two worksheets (Panel1, Panel2) simultaneously, or will it need to be executed on both independently?

Thanks so much for any and all help, I am incredibly grateful. I would continue trying to work the solution out myself, but apparently I've been spending too much time on this task...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try this. The sub will look for a specific string in a given range and remove all lines (and whole lines) that contain the string.

```
Sub CleanRange(R As Range, T As String)
Dim I As Long, F As Object
Dim M As Long, N As Long, P As Long, Q As Long
M = R.Row
N = R.Column
P = M + R.Rows.Count - 1
Q = N + R.Columns.Count - 1
I = M
While I <= P
    Set F = Range(Cells(I, N), Cells(I, Q)).Find(T, LookIn:=xlValues)
    If F Is Nothing Then
        I = I + 1
    Else
        Rows(I).Delete
        P = P - 1
    End If
Wend
End Sub
```

Call for instance

```
Call CleanRange(Range("A1:C8"), "2")
```

If you are looking for T in a single column, you may simplify and use Cells(I, K).Value directly.

It's possible to adapt this to operate on several sheets, or to look for several strings.

---

If you are always looking in column B, you can write

```
Sub CleanRange(R As Range, T As String)
Dim I As Long
Dim M As Long, N As Long, P As Long, Q As Long
M = R.Row
N = R.Column
P = M + R.Rows.Count - 1
Q = N + R.Columns.Count - 1
I = M
While I <= P
    If Cells(I, 2).Value = T Then
        Rows(I).Delete
        P = P - 1
    Else
        I = I + 1
    End If
Wend
End Sub
```

---

Or even

```
Sub CleanRange(R1 As Long, R2 As Long, T As String)
Dim I As Long
Dim M As Long, N As Long, P As Long, Q As Long
M = R1
P = R2
I = M
While I <= P
    If Cells(I, 2).Value = T Then
        Rows(I).Delete
        P = P - 1
    Else
        I = I + 1
    End If
Wend
End Sub
```

Notice the While is important, instead of the more obvious For loop, because as you delete rows, the last row to visit moves up, so the limit of the loop is reduced (that's why there is P = P - 1).

---

Then, if you want to call this sub in another sub, you will have

```
Sub Something(...)
!Declarations
!Do whatever you want here (initialisation...)

!Then do the call, with the appropriate range and string, here is an example
Call CleanRange(Range("A1:C100"), "2")

!Do whatever you want
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your response. Is there a way to include this functionality in the above mentioned Macro? Or maybe to at least function similarly to this script?

`Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()Dim rCell As Range
For Each rCell In Range("A45:R45")
rCell.EntireColumn.Hidden = (rCell.Value = "HIDE")
Next rCell
End Sub`
That one seems to run constantly in the background and modifies the worksheet when values are changed. I'm trying to minimize keystrokes as much as possible. Sorry if this should be obvious, as I said, I am very much an Excel/VBA novice.

Comment: @SeedySea If you copy paste the CleanRange sub into a module, it becomes available, then you can call it with the line "Call CleanRange..." above. You have to put this call with the correct argument in any place where you want it to happen (maybe inside Worksheet_Calculate, if you wish).

Comment: So, if I wanted to add this to the Macro above and have it be the first function that executed, would I add the call this way? `...ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Panel1").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("C1:C18") _
    , SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
With Call CleanRange(Range("A1:C8"), "2")
End With...` Also, I'm not entirely sure what you meant with `Cells(I, K).Value` For this worksheet I want it to only look in Column B for the exact text string RTA, so how would that look? Also, if I wanted to modify it to search, for example, Columns B and C to find

Comment: and delete rows that contain the numeral 0 in either of those specific columns, how would that look? Sorry, I don't mean to be difficult, I'm just really trying to understand how all of this functions. I really appreciate your assistance.